# Trouble with codeigniter redirect

Tags: codeigniter

I try to redirect a search to the right controller. This works fine if I have no special chars in the searchkey. If I have special keys in it I get an error from codeigniter:

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Here is my code:

```
public function search()
{
    $searchkey = urlencode($this->input->post('searchkey'));
    switch ($this->input->post('searchtype')) {
        case 'request':     redirect('portal/requests/search/'.$searchkey, 'refresh');
                            break;
        case 'offers':      redirect('portal/offers/search/'.$searchkey, 'refresh');
                            break;
        case 'projects':    redirect('portal/projects/search/'.$searchkey, 'refresh');
                            break;
        default:            redirect('portal/requests/search/'.$searchkey, 'refresh');
                            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe input->post() encode them all for you so they are already safe

Comment: Why do you need to send the search along with the url. I belive it's to show the search key back in the Search field. is it? . if it's so you can use session to set and retrieve parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because you cannot put 'special' characters in your url

i.e. if I search for "test" I am taken to portal/projects/search/test

but if I search for test@#$)*&&f - you cannot have a url with some of those characters

to solve this either perform a validation on the post, and make the search term only have [numbers and letters](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('searchtype', 'Search Type', 'required|alpha_numeric');
```

or you have to 'pass' the search term to function in another way - perhaps using [flash data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), so that the search term is not passed by a url

edit: default url chars for your reference (from line 129 (approx) of config.php)

```
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Comment: But why do codeigniter have problems with a string that is urlencoded? If I paste "/portal/requests/search/%C3%84nderung+am" manual directly to the browser, there are the same probs?!

Comment: its a security feature - around line 129 of the config.php defines it. Please dont change it - its there for a reason...

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';  <- these are default - should not be changed

Comment: OK, I think I use flashdata. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jquery and post the searchkey to controller if its necceseary.